# Dynamic table in JSP and Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I am writing an application using Spring MVC and Hibernate. In one of my application pages, the JSP page consists of dynamically generated tables based on the criteria specified by the end-user.  For example, the end-user enters the "number of employees" on the page and upon clicking submit, the next page shows all the companies that have a number of employees equal to or greater than the value entered by the end-user. For each company, a separate / individual  table is generated, header of the table shows the name of the company from database (This part is working completely fine). Now in the table for the company itself, I want to display data for that company only and likewise, every table header will display the name of the company and the data for that company only. Any ideas of how can I display the data for company in the table. Below is my code

Controller

```
                    Int numberOfemployees // This value is entered by the end user    
                    List<Company> companies = companyService.listAllCompany(numberOfEmployees );   


                    ModelAndView companiesResults = new ModelAndView("companies-result");
                    CompanyForm companyForm  = new CompanyForm();

                    companyForm.setCompanies(companies);
                    companiesResults.addObject("company", companies);

                    for (Company company : companies) {

                        int company_id  = company.getCompany_id(); //Get id of the company to get its attributes/data from database

                    List<CompanyAttribute> companyAttributes =companyService.listCompanyAttributes(company_id);


                    }


                    companyForm.setCompanyAttributes(companyAttributes);

                    companiesResult.addObject("companyForm", companyForm);                  
                    companiesResult.addObject("companyAttributte", companyAttributes);              

                        }
```

Below is my JSP

```
<c:forEach items="${companyForm.companies}" var="company" varStatus="status">

              <h6>${company.company_name}</h6>              
              <div class="table-responsive">            
                <table>


                  <thead>

                    <tr>                     
                      <th>Company portfolio</th>
                      <th>Company points</th>                                                                       
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

              <tbody>                 
                   <c:forEach items="${companyForm.companyAttributes}" var="companyAttribute"  varStatus="status">                              
                        <tr>
                            <td>${companyAttribute.portfolio}</td>
                            <td>${companyAttribute.points}</td> 

                        </tr>                                                                                                                                           
                    </c:forEach>                                           
                  </tbody>                                                    
                </table>

    </c:forEach>
```

I will appreciate any ideas on how can I display data for each company in its table. My approach is showing me empty table for every company. Should I use some kind of scripplet in JSP page or is there any other approach. I am new to JSP and Spring MVC, any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:hibernate] and [tag:spring-data-jpa]? The question only talks about JSP and Spring MVC controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few years ago and solved it that way:

```
// In my controller
mav.addObject("order", order);

// In my jsp
<c:forEach items="${order.articles}" var="article">
...
</c:forEach>
```

This is **not** working. But then I tried this

```
// In my controller
mav.addObject("articles", order.getOrderArticles());

// In my jsp
<c:forEach items="${articles}" var="article">
```

it works as expected. As you can see I added the list of articles as another object in my model. And then it is possible to iterate over this object in the jsp.

Comment: did u used only one loop "articles" in jsp or two loops (one for "order" and otherone for "articles". Thanks in advance

Comment: I looped only over my articles in that case.

Comment: ok, and how did u displayed order (like order name / order number).

Comment: It's no problem to use ${order.name} etc. and ${articles.artnum} or whatever. The only thing which is not working is to directly iterate over the collections in orders.